# What is the most effective way of communicating with PHP daemon?

Tags: php, messaging

I did some PHP daemon and now I want my PHP webapp to communicate with it, e.g. send XML document to it and receive response after some time. As I would like to avoid file operations over the network (as it involves FTP), what would be the ideal way of sending this document?
The PHP daemons and PHP webapps are on different servers.
I have investigated various options so far:

- ActiveMQ, but that adds additional bloatware
- TCP Sockets (however it's hard to do it as the PHP daemon is
  single-threaded and very busy sometimes)
- FTP, SCP to send the file
- NFS / CIFS
- Using database

If the messaging server looks like the best option, what would be best suited for PHP? I would like to avoid centralized, single messaging server because it's difficult to approve firewall rules, and the network is very big, complex and very fail-prone.
So that would require star-shaped network of messaging servers, and because of that they would need to very lightweight, easy to deploy and with no difficult dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is obvious: Use TCP but don't use a single threaded programming language for a TCP daemon.

If you want to use PHP for the *workers*, maybe because you wish them to use a shared PHP library, you can code a most minimal daemon in a programming language which supports threads, and forwards the requests to PHP helper scripts (or pooled, single threaded TCP daeamons if you want to deploy the workers on different hosts, which is good for scalability)

However, a software which fulfils the requirements exists already: [`Gearman`](http://gearman.org/)

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for. Having the client (webapp) and the worker code (indeed using same PHP libraries), the Client API, Job Server and Worker API is something which just fits perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Communicating with your daemon consists of two completely different aspects:

- Send data **to** the daemon
- Receive data **from** the daemon

I learned this the hard way, when I had to solve a very similar problem.

Sending data to the daemon is limited by the fact, that the single-threaded daemon cannot easily listen. I solved it this way:

- When the daemon is idle, it polls a SysV-Messagequeue
- When a consumer wants to request the daemon, it creates a command file reachable via an unguessable URL. It then transmits that URL to the daemon's SysV-Messagequeue (see below for how)
- THe idling daemon sees the message, fetches the command file via the URL, works on it
- The command file has an URL where to post the result to
- The daemon uses cURL to deliver it.

This comes quite natural for a webapp as a consumer - the heavy lifting is completely done as web requests: Both directions are initiated by the daemon, whenever it is idle.

Now for how to get a message into the daemon: The easiest way is to have some sort of server running there

- If a webserver is already running on the target machine, use a tiny script, that just accepts the URL from a well-defined set of consumers and queues it
- If not, inetd or xinetd with either a simple shell script or a few lines of C code can do the trick
- If you want something a bit more robust you can start a queuer command via SSH

We use all three variations in production with excellent results: If the consumer keeps track of the already-worked-on command files, a double-execution because of a flaky network can easily be ruled out.

Comment: Nice answer, especially: "If a target server is already running on that machine ... use it!" ... That's it! However, you might have a look into `Gearman` though.

Comment: @hek2mgl I use gearman extensively - but I thought it a bad fit for the OQ: He said *lightweight, easy to deploy and with no difficult dependencies*, which is only borderline true with gearman (at least in many distros)

Comment: Yes, that's true. However, I've added my answer anyway. For a special purpose, a custom solution but like that, would even being leightweight. The main point is, that it cannot being done having PHP only as PHP is single threaded.

Comment: I managed to build `Gearman` on most of the distros now and I am looking on Java version too now, however the C version also works OK but it has indeed tons of dependencies but less than let's say PHP itself.

Comment: @AndrewSmith I am all **for** Gearman! My point was, that in a network, that is *very big, complex and very fail-prone*, possibly consists of very different OSes, deploying Gearman might be hard.

Comment: Yeah tell me more I am still building the dependencies :-) Boost taking very long to build on old machines.